# iOS CollectionView Header doesn't show

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

Im trying to add a segmented control onto my header but I am having trouble doing this. In this example to make things simpler I am adding a Label but that is also not showing. Can someone tell me why this is not happening?

```
import UIKit

class SessionsViewController: UICollectionViewController , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareCollectionView()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Log Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "plus") , style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.honePalette.accent
    }


    func prepareSegmentedControll()->UISegmentedControl{
        let items = ["Future Sessions", "Past Sessions"]
        let control = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        control.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        control.tintColor = UIColor.honePalette.accent

        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        control.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], for: .normal)
        return control
    }

    func prepareCollectionView(){
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView?.register(sessionsInfo.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    // return of the number per item per section
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    //this is when the collection is clicked
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
        print("this is index path:", indexPath)

    }

    // this is the cell of the collection returning initialized with the SessionsInfo
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as? sessionsInfo
        myCell?.sessionLabel.text = "cell  \(indexPath.row)"
        return myCell!
    }
    // this is when the size of the cell returns
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 10, height: 80)
    }

    // return supplementary view
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {



        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath)

        let label = UILabel(frame: headerView.bounds)
        label.text = "Top View"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "helvetica", size: 12)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        //headerView.headerLabel.text = "header"

        return headerView


    }


    func handleLogout(){
        BaseServices.baseServices.signOut()
        present(LoginViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}


class headerInfo : UICollectionReusableView{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupHeader()
    }

    var headerLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "HEADER"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupHeader(){

        backgroundColor = UIColor.honePalette.raindrops
        addSubview(headerLabel)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":headerLabel]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":headerLabel]))

    }

}


class sessionsInfo: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupSessions()
    }

    var sessionLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "sessionView"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    var sessionTimeLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    var sessionLocationLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    func setupSessions(){

        backgroundColor = UIColor.honePalette.raindrops
        addSubview(sessionLabel)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":sessionLabel]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":sessionLabel]))

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code in a new project, and you are missing two key steps: registering the supplementary view and setting the size of your header.

In your `prepareCollectionView` function, you also need to register the header view:

```
collectionView?.register(headerInfo.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
```

You also need to implement another delegate function giving the size of your header view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) // fix to be your intended size
}
```

Here is proof that it works. (I didn't have access to your custom colors, which is why everything is orange and gray.)

[image: collection view header screenshot]

Comment: Is there a way to make the header view unscrollable so that it always stays on top and the collection can still be scroll-able ?

Comment: If you want the view to stay at the top, you can make it a view separate from the collection view, just positioned directly above it. The purpose of collection view headers and footers is that they scroll with the contents of the collection view.

Comment: so what should I use in terms of header for when the content view moves and the date as a header for example stays until the next date view header comes? is that UITableView?

Comment: I would look into "fixed headers" or "sticky headers" here on Stack Overflow. There are a lot of great answers which describe exactly what you want to achieve. This is most commonly done with UITableView's.